# What is the cause of ERROR 1327 "Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in..." when ROBOCOPY is copying files?

Tags: robocopy

I am using ROBOCOPY to copy some files from a remote share to a local folder on a server. The file set is fairly large (about 500,000 files). The copy process starts and runs successfully for an hour or two and then ROBOCOPY starts reporting an error on every attempted copy. The errors are just like this except for different folders:

```
2019/02/22 08:22:16 ERROR 1327 (0x0000052F) Accessing Destination Directory E:\PDM_DATA\PDMVaultTest\0\000cfa40\

Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

The ROBOCOPY command line I am running is:
`ROBOCOPY \\REMOTESERVER\PDM_DATA\PDMVault E:\PDM_DATA\PDMVaultTest /mir /r:1 /w:1 /log:E:\PDM_DATA\CopyPDMVaultFromProduction.log`

I'm logged into the server with local admin credentials and running the command prompt with the Run As Administrator option.

### Update

I tried running this same copy operation with a program called SyncBackPro. That program was very slow and the same error message occurred as with ROBOCOPY.

However, when SyncBackPro reported the error it clearly indicated that it was failing when trying to read from the remote share. The remote share is on a virtual server hosted on AWS which is joined to our domain. I suspect that the slower wide area network connection that is required to communicate with the AWS host from the on premises destination server is the likely cause of my problem.

I did give the /b option with ROBOCOPY a try but that did not help.

Comment: Hi, please run the task with an account know from both side, is it on a workgroug or a domain ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 The servers are on a domain and I am connected with a domain account. The particular domain account is a local admin on the remote server that hosts the share and the local server I am trying to copy to.

Comment: Log into the remote server, and check the security of that folder; 000cfa40 I suspect someone put only one group / user in it, but stripped your domain account from the folder security, the error is just the robocopy try to rewrite the same security, and lock you out of it

Comment: @yagmoth555 Good suggestion. I compared the permissions on the folder that failed with one of the folders that worked. They have the exact same permissions granted to the same users/groups.

Comment: I completed one other troubleshooting step. I opened the source and destination folders in Window Explorer windows and did a drag and drop copy. This worked error free.

Comment: Try with the script, but without the run as administrator please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90106/discussion-between-matthew-macfarland-and-yagmoth555).

Comment: Make sure you use robocopy in backup mode... `/b` if that doesn’t work also try `/zb`